# Regarding the lines to be displayed separately in console

Tags: java

I have implemented the idea  as shown below by keeping 3 different files in the Test Folder

```
public class FileCountLine {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        File directory = new File("C:/Test/");
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
                int lineCount = 0;
                try {
                    for (lineCount = 0; scanner.nextLine() != null; lineCount++);
                } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                    result.put(file.getName(), lineCount);
                }
            }}

        System.out.println(result);     
            }}
```

but the outcome as output, I am getting for files that is counting the number of lines of code in them  is all coming in one line itself as shown below..

```
{ValidateWagRewardsRedemptionOptionPPI.java=73, IWalgreensRewardsPosLogSupport.java=134, WagEnrollmentInfoLine.java=111}
```

Please advise I want the outcome to be in the format as output as shown below

```
WalgreensRewardsPosLogSupport.java=134,
WagEnrollmentInfoLine.java=111,
ValidateRewardsAARPManualEntryPPI.java=67
```

That is each file in new line itself, please advise what necessary changes is need to be done for that.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `System.out.println(result);` with

```
for(String e : result.keySet())
    System.out.println(e+"="+result(e)+"\n")
```

What you were getting was the default toString for a HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : result.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Integer value = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println(key+"="+value+",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't print HashMap like this

```
System.out.println(result);
```

Use this

```
for( Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry:result.entrySet()){
  System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" = "+entry.getValue());
}
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
for( Map.Entry<String, Integer> m : result.entrySet())

{

  System.out.println(m.getKey()+" = "+m.getValue());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

class FileCountLine {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        File directory = new File("/home/joker/Projects/eclipse");
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
                int lineCount = 0;
                try {
                    for (lineCount = 0; scanner.nextLine() != null; lineCount++);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    result.put(file.getName(), lineCount);
                }
            }}

        Set set = result.entrySet() ;
        Iterator itr = set.iterator();
       while(itr.hasNext())
       {
           System.out.println(itr.next()+"\n");
       }


            }}
```